# Cordova Push Plugin build error: variable M

Tags: android, cordova, cmd, push

I installed https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugin-push to have push notifications in my app. When building I get this errors:

H:\T2S\platforms\android\src\com\adobe\phonegap\push\GCMIntentService.java:390: cannot find symbol
symbol  : variable M
location: class android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES
                        Log.d(LOG_TAG, "Version: " + android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT + " = " + android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.M);
                                                                                                                              ^
H:\T2S\platforms\android\src\com\adobe\phonegap\push\GCMIntentService.java:391: cannot find symbol
symbol  : variable M
location: class android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES
                        if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT <= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
                                                                                              ^
H:\T2S\platforms\android\src\com\adobe\phonegap\push\GCMIntentService.java:401: cannot find symbol
symbol  : variable M
location: class android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES
                        if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT <= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
                                                                                              ^
Note: Some input files use unchecked or unsafe operations.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
3 errors

cordova -version: 6.3.0

java -version: 1.8.0_73

I have also installed the latest Packages in SDK of: Android Support Repository; Google Play Services; Google Repository

Comment: How do you add plugin? Can you show the code?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Thanks for the comment but the problem is solved ;)
I used the wrong version of the plugin

Comment: hey can you share these things?

Comment: Yes, You should add the correct solution so other can benefit from it

Answer (score 0):

Could be a plugin has the wrong version. Here is the easiest way to reinstall all the cordova plugins:

```
npm install -g cordova-plugins-reinstall

cdv-reinstall
```